# Dual-Cones Doubt.

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm doing the [Convex Opt. mooc](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/Engineering/CVX101/Winter2014/about) taught by Stephen Boyd offered by Standford Lagunita. This question is being asked:

> Consider the cone: $\ K= \{(x_1,x_2) \ | \ 0 \le\ x_1 \le\ x_2 \} \subseteq {\mathbf{R}}^2$.
>   Which of the following are true?

And then we have 2 options:

1) $ \ (1,3)\le _K(3,4) $

The definition of generalized inequality says:
$$ x \le _Ky $$

$$ y-x\in K $$

Which leave us:
$(3,4)-(1,3)=(2,1)$, which is false since the restriction for our cone says that $x_1 \le\ x_2$

No issues in there. But in the next one I don't know what should be the right procedure, therefore I don't know how to answer.

2) $(-1,2) \ge _{K^*}0$

The definitions for generalized inequealities are all in the form of $ x \le y $, how should I proceed? Can I flip the terms $x$ and $y$ and say this?

$$x-y \in K^*$$

Is it wrong to assume this? If not, I'd have to define what is $K^*$ given $K$, right? the restrictions stay the same? how can I do that?

Sorry, I know this is simple for a lot of you, but I need some help to figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: Unless otherwise stated, $(-1,2)\geq_{K^\ast}0$ means the same thing as $0\leq_{K^\ast}(-1,2)$.  So, the question is asking whether $(-1,2)\in K^\ast$.  I assume that $K^\ast$ is the dual cone to $K$, so you'll need to compute that.

Comment: @MichaelBurr thank you. But how would I get that? Given the restriction for $ K $, it means the pair of points $ (x_1,x_2) $ are all in the first quadrant of $ {\mathbf{R}}^2 $ (though they don't cover the whole quadrant), that way I can imagine better the subset I'm speaking. Knowing that, where would be $ K^* $ located? 

What region/set of $ {\mathbf{R}}^2 $ can make a non-negative inner product with the set that describes the restrictions of $ K $?

Comment: There are standard constructions for $K^\ast$.  One way is to draw the normal lines to the lines $0=x_1$ and $x_1=x_2$.  One of the regions formed by these lines is the dual cone to $K$.  In this case, the dual cone is formed from $x_2\geq 0$ and $x_2+x_1\geq 0$.  This is the first quadrant and the part of the second quadrant above the line $x_2=-x_1$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I think I just saw it and reviewed that part of the lecture. This helped me a lot, thank you! :)